# Google Sheets V4 API - Query Google Sheets by Search Criteria(s)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am integrating my Spring Boot API with Google Sheets API, and was curious to see if anyone know of a good way to query the spreadsheet by criteria.

From what I can observe, I don't see a good way to actually achieve this.  The only way I can think of is to retrieve the whole data back, and then filter out the results based on the search parameters.  But this could become an issue if the data becomes too large (let's say if the spreadsheet has 30000 rows).

**Thank you** in advance, and please let me know if you have a better idea that could achieve this!

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, for example, is this information useful for your situation? https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage In your case, it uses the URL with the query parameter. If that was not useful, I apologize.